# What Erlang data structure to use for ordered set with the possibility to do lookups?

Tags: database, data-structures, erlang, set

I am working on a problem where I need to remember the order of events I receive but also I need to lookup the event based on it's id. How can I do this efficiently in Erlang if possible without a third party library? Note that I have many potentially ephemeral actors with each their own events (already considered mnesia but it requires atoms for the tables and the tables would stick around if my actor died).

```
-record(event, {id, timestamp, type, data}).
```

Comment: They're not *actors* they are *processes*. /petpeeve

Comment: @zxq9 Close enough for me

Comment: To each his own. (^.^) I am particular about this only because the terms actually mean something slightly different. Erlang was developed in isolation of Carl Hewitt's conceptual "actor model" of computation but happened to have a very similar style to it, and has only recently been promoted as an "actor-model language". It turns out that several Erlangers (including myself) have re-invented *nearly the same thing* in other contexts in ignorance of Erlang/OTP! Though "actors" often equate to "processes", in Erlang they *really* are "processes". Pedantic, maybe, but here we are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the details included in the discussion in comments on Michael's answer, a *very* simple, workable approach would be to create a tuple in your process state variable that stores the order of events separately from the K-V store of events.

Consider:

```
%%% Some type definitions so we know exactly what we're dealing with.
-type id()     :: term().
-type type()   :: atom().
-type data()   :: term().
-type ts()     :: calendar:datetime().
-type event()  :: {id(), ts(), type(), data()}.
-type events() :: dict:dict(id(), {type(), data(), ts()}).

% State record for the process.
% Should include whatever else the process deals with.
-record(s,
        {log    :: [id()],
         events :: event_store()}).

%%% Interface functions we will expose over this module.
-spec lookup(pid(), id()) -> {ok, event()} | error.
lookup(Pid, ID) ->
    gen_server:call(Pid, {lookup, ID}).

-spec latest(pid()) -> {ok, event()} | error.
latest(Pid) ->
    gen_server:call(Pid, get_latest).

-spec notify(pid(), event()) -> ok.
notify(Pid, Event) ->
    gen_server:cast(Pid, {new, Event}).

%%% gen_server handlers
handle_call({lookup, ID}, State#s{events = Events}) ->
    Result = find(ID, Events),
    {reply, Result, State};
handle_call(get_latest, State#s{log = [Last | _], events = Events}) ->
    Result = find(Last, Events),
    {reply, Result, State};
% ... and so on...

handle_cast({new, Event}, State) ->
    {ok, NewState} = catalog(Event, State),
    {noreply, NewState};
% ...

%%% Implementation functions
find(ID, Events) ->
    case dict:find(ID, Events) of
        {Type, Data, Timestamp} -> {ok, {ID, Timestamp, Type, Data}};
        Error                   -> Error
    end.

catalog({ID, Timestamp, Type, Data},
        State#s{log = Log, events = Events}) ->
    NewEvents = dict:store(ID, {Type, Data, Timestamp}, Events),
    NewLog = [ID | Log],
    {ok, State#s{log = NewLog, events = NewEvents}}.
```

This is a *completely* straightforward implementation and hides the details of the data structure behind the interface of the process. Why did I pick a dict? Just because (its easy). Without knowing your requirements better I really have no reason to pick a dict over a map over a gb_tree, etc. If you have relatively small data (hundreds or thousands of things to store) the performance isn't usually noticeably different among these structures.

The important thing is that you clearly identify *what messages this process should respond to* and then force yourself to stick to it elsewhere in your project code by *creating an interface of exposed functions* over this module. Behind that you can swap out the dict for something else. If you really only need the latest event ID and won't ever need to pull the Nth event from the sequence log then you could ditch the log and just keep the last event's ID in the record instead of a list.

So get something very simple like this working first, then determine if it actually suits your need. If it doesn't then tweak it. If this works for now, just run with it -- *don't obsess over performance or storage* (until you are really forced to).

If you find later on that you have a performance problem switch out the dict and list for something else -- maybe gb_tree or orddict or ETS or whatever. The point is to get something working right now so you have a base from which to evaluate the functionality and run benchmarks if necessary. (The *vast* majority of the time, though, I find that whatever I start out with as a specced prototype turns out to be *very* close to whatever the final solution will be.)

Answer (score 2):

Your question makes it clear you want to lookup by ID, but it's not entirely clear if you want to lookup or traverse your data by or based on time, and what operations you might want to perform in that regard; you say "remember the order of events" but storing your records with an index of the ID field will accomplish that.

If you only have to lookup by ID then any of the usual suspects will work as a suitable storage engines, so ets, gb_trees and dict for example would be good. Don't use mnesia unless you need the transactions and safety and all those good features; mnesia is good, but there is a high performance price to be paid for all that stuff, and it's not clear you need it, from your question anyway.

If you do want to lookup or traverse your data by or based on time, then consider an ets table of `ordered_set`. If that can do what you need then it's probably a good choice. In that case you would employ two tables, one `set` to provide a hash lookup by ID and another `ordered_set` to lookup or traverse by timestamp.

If you have two different lookup methods like this there's no getting around the fact you need two indexes. You could store the whole record in both, or, assuming your IDs are unique, you could store the ID as the data in the `ordered_set`. Which you choose is really a matter of trade off of storage utilisation and read and wrote performance.

Comment: I want to be able to get the new oldest event and lookup or remove arbitrary events based on id.

Comment: Probably `ordered_set` ets tables would work well for you then, as you have `ets:last/1`. BUT if you only ever need to get the last one out by time, then you could use just a `set` ets table, lookup by ID, and remember the latest record separately couldn't you? You'd only need one table then and significantly reduce your overhead. If events always arrive in order then this latest record is always the last record received, but if not then it's not much harder just to compare the timestamps.

Comment: I tried to do it separately but the problem is what data structure to use for the ordering? `queue` is implemented with a list from what I understand and `ordsets` is the same. So it wouldn't be efficient for removal.

Comment: Queue uses lists, but it's not just the same as a list. Trouble is now we're getting into the nitty gritty your problem is becoming so specific it's quite difficult to really know what the absolutely best answer is going to be. Your question was general, but, and so you go a fairly general answer, but now you get down to it, the perfect choice might depend also on how many events you are storing at a time to be fair. A small enough list can out perform some of the more advanced structures.

Comment: Not sure why you are considering queue, I can only imagine it's because you want a pipe where you push on one end and get off the other, but your question doesn't really read like that... I think you should consider creating a facade module that implements your storage requirements, and then try implementing it with the most likely candidates, such as ETS table, gb_trees, and queue if you think that is appropriate... then you can benchmark your implementations for your required operations.

Comment: It could be a number lets say a 1000 items for each process with up to 1000 processes.

Comment: I think you should either use gb_trees or ets set, remembering the 'latest' event separately, if that works for you, OR use two ets tables, a set and an ordered_set. A queue doesn't sound like it fits your requirements as set out in your question. If you are in doubt though you will have to benchmark.